# Why does the swap mapper file get created even though I removed it from /etc/crypttab?

Tags: debian, luks, swap

I have this line in /etc/crypttab for my swap partition:

```
luks-4205519b-f3fe-468f-b05e-44f25f6882a4 UUID=4205519b-f3fe-468f-b05e-44f25f6882a4     /crypto_keyfile.bin luks,keyscript=/bin/cat
```

I commented it out so it now looks like this:

```
# luks-4205519b-f3fe-468f-b05e-44f25f6882a4 UUID=4205519b-f3fe-468f-b05e-44f25f6882a4     /crypto_keyfile.bin luks,keyscript=/bin/cat
```

I rebooted but the mapper file `/dev/mapper/luks-4205519b-f3fe-468f-b05e-44f25f6882a4` still gets created. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your initramfs; there’s a copy of `crypttab` there.

On Debian derivatives, run

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```